# Hoare Logic: If-statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, computer-science

[image]

Can someone explain the first assignment and implied? We prove bottom to up and I don't follor after the $(1=x+1)$ if-Statement. This is what my book says about the assignment rule:

> , if we wish to show that ψ holds in the state
> after the assignment $x = E$, we must show that $ψ[E/x]$ holds before the
> assignment.

But how is that the case here?

Comment: Not very clear... What are you trying to prove?

Comment: That {T} P {y=x+1} given the code you see in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what book you're using, so I'm gonna stick to the formulation on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) (hope that's Ok :]).
There are two things going on in the first four lines of your example, one application of the [Consequence rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#Consequence_rule) and one application of the [Assignment axiom schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#Assignment_axiom_schema).

Set
$$\psi' = (x + 1 - 1 = 0 \to 1 = x + 1) \land (\neg (x + 1 - 1 = 0) \to x + 1 = x + 1)$$
$$\psi = (a - 1 = 0 \to 1 = x + 1) \land (\neg (a - 1 = 0) \to a = x + 1)$$

and notice that

$$\psi' = \psi[x + 1/a].$$

So applying the Assignment axiom schema (the rule you've mentioned) we're allowed to derive

$$\overline{\{\psi'\}\ a = x + 1\ \{\psi\}}$$

that being lines 2-4.
The Consequence  rule allows us to strengthen the precondition ($\psi'$), since $\psi'$ is valid we have

$$\top \to \psi'$$
$$\psi \to \psi$$

and can derive

$$\frac{\top \to \psi',\ \overline{\{\psi'\}\ a = x + 1\ \{\psi\}},\ \psi \to \psi}{\{\top\}\ a = x + 1\ \{\psi\}}.$$

The remaining lines prove $\{\psi\}\ \texttt{if } ... \texttt{ else } ...\ \{y = x + 1\}$, so applying the [Rule of composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#Rule_of_composition) you can derive the required result.